# how to launch apollo server v4 in nestjs from my apollo.service.ts file

Tags: graphql, nestjs, microservices, apollo-server

I am running a Nestjs API using apollo federation in a monorepo with an Auth icroservice. I the Auth microservice I have an apollo.service.ts file I am using to launch apollo server v4. I using the following dependencies:

package.json:

```
"@apollo/federation": "~0.38.1",
    "@apollo/gateway": "~2.4.2",
    "@apollo/server": "~4.7.1",
    "@apollo/subgraph": "~2.4.2",
    "@apollo/usage-reporting-protobuf": "~4.1.0",
    "@apollo/utils.fetcher": "~3.0.0",
    "@graphql-tools/load": "~7.8.14",
    "@graphql-tools/load-files": "~6.6.1",
    "@graphql-tools/merge": "~8.4.2",
    "@liaoliaots/nestjs-redis": "~9.0.5",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "~11.0.5",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "~2.3.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "~11.0.5",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "~10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/microservices": "~9.4.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.4.0",
...........
```

thi is my apollo.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { buildFederatedSchema } from '@apollo/federation';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { join } from 'path';
import { loadFiles } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';
import { mergeResolvers, mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';

import express from 'express';
import { AuthResolver } from '../auth/auth.resolver';

@Injectable()
export class ApolloService implements OnModuleInit {
  private server: ApolloServer;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private authResolver: AuthResolver,
  ) {}

  private getTokenForRequest(req: any): Promise<string | null> {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    if (authHeader) {
      const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1]; 
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    }

    // If there's no authHeader, we just return null
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    const port = this.configService.get<number>('SERVER_PORT');

    // Load GraphQL type definitions and resolvers from the filesystem
    const typesArray = await loadFiles(join(__dirname, '../**/*.graphql'));

    const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray);

    // Load resolvers
    const resolvers = {
      Query: {
        login: this.authResolver.login.bind(this.authResolver),
        refreshToken: this.authResolver.refreshToken.bind(this.authResolver),
      },
    };

    const schema = buildFederatedSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }]);

    this.server = new ApolloServer<any>({
      schema,
  context: async ({ req, res }) => ({
        token: await this.getTokenForRequest(req),
      }),
    });    ******ERROR1: 

    await this.server.start();
    const app = express();

    app.use(
      '/graphql',
      // cors(), // assuming you have 'cors' package installed
      this.server.getMiddleware({}), ****ERROR2
    );

    this.app.listen(port).then(({ url }) => {
      console.log(` Auth service ready at ${url}`);
    });
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find the correct implementation for the context object in ERROR1. I am getting this error:

```
 Argument of type '{ schema: GraphQLSchema; context: ({ req, res }: { req: any; res: any; }) => Promise<{ token: string; }>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ApolloServerOptions<MyContext>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'context' does not exist in type 'ApolloServerOptionsWithSchema<MyContext>'
```

and in ERROR2 I can't seem to locate the middleware. I am getting this error:

Property 'getMiddleware' does not exist on type 'ApolloServer'

I am not sure what's going on here. I suspect I am having issues with the integration of Nestjs and Apollo Server. I am using express to resolve the issue but it doesn't seem to work either. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

**EDIT**
So if my apollo.service.ts now looks like this:

```
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { buildFederatedSchema } from '@apollo/federation';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { join } from 'path';
import { loadFiles } from '@graphql-tools/load-files';
import { mergeResolvers, mergeTypeDefs } from '@graphql-tools/merge';

import express from 'express';
import { AuthResolver } from '../auth/auth.resolver';

@Injectable()
export class ApolloService implements OnModuleInit {
  private server: ApolloServer;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private authResolver: AuthResolver,
  ) {}

  private getTokenForRequest(req: any): Promise<string | null> {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

    if (authHeader) {
      const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1]; // The token is after the word 'Bearer '
      return Promise.resolve(token);
    }

    // If there's no authHeader, we just return null
    return Promise.resolve(null);
  }

  async onModuleInit() {
    const port = this.configService.get<number>('SERVER_PORT');

    // Load GraphQL type definitions and resolvers from the filesystem
    const typesArray = await loadFiles(join(__dirname, '../**/*.graphql'));

    const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typesArray);

    // Load resolvers
    const resolvers = {
      Query: {
        login: this.authResolver.login.bind(this.authResolver),
        refreshToken: this.authResolver.refreshToken.bind(this.authResolver),
      },
    };

    const schema = buildFederatedSchema([{ typeDefs, resolvers }]);
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
    });

    const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
      context: async ({ req, res }) => ({
        token: await this.getTokenForRequest(req),
      }),
      listen: { port: parseInt(process.env.PORT) },
    });

    console.log(` Auth service ready at ${url}`);
  }
}
```

I am now faced with the problem of where do I launch my apollo server? I want to launch it in my main.ts file as per usual but I don't see how to incorporate the startStandaloneServer in main.ts. How would I access the server and context when there are actually identified in auth.module? my current main.ts looks like this:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SharedService } from '@app/shared-library';
import { Logger, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
  const logger = new Logger('AUTH Microservice');

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AuthModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.enableCors();
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  const sharedService = app.get(SharedService);
  const queue = configService.get('RABBITMQ_NOTIFY_QUEUE');

  const port = configService.get('PORT') || 4001;
  app.connectMicroservice<any>(sharedService.getRmqOptions(queue));

 *****I believe I need to integrate startStandAloneServer HERE*****
  app.listen(port); // http access from flash-gateway
  logger.log(`Auth Microservice is listening on port ${port}`);

  
bootstrap();
```

This is my AuthModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { ApolloService } from './apollo.service';
import { AuthResolver } from './auth.resolver';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import {
  ApolloFederationDriver,
  ApolloFederationDriverConfig,
} from '@nestjs/apollo';
//import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from '@apollo/server';
import configuration from '@app/shared-library/config/configuration';
import { join } from 'path';
import { Neo4jModule } from '@app/shared-library/neo4j/neo4j.module';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { RedisServerModule } from '@app/shared-library/redis-server/redis-server.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
     // context: ({ req }: any) => ({ req }), **moved to apollo.service.ts
      // formatResponse: (response) => {
      //   if (response.errors) {
      //     response.errors = response.errors.map((error) => {
      //       return {
      //         message:
      //           error.extensions.exception.response.message || error.message,
      //       };
      //     });
      //   }
      //   return response;
      // },

      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.classes.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      playground: false,
      // plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault()],
    }),
    Neo4jModule.forRootAsync(), // optional custom config to allow module to use diff db and creds
    RedisServerModule.forRoot(process.env.REDIS_URL),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [ConfigService, AuthService, AuthResolver, ApolloService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Seems like I am dancing between Nestjs and Apollo Server....no fun. I would certainly appreciate some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Apollo Server v4+ which has a different startup pattern relative to v3. You need to use `startStandAloneServer` to use the context.

Example:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

// Passing an ApolloServer instance to the `startStandaloneServer` function:
//  1. creates an Express app
//  2. installs your ApolloServer instance as middleware
//  3. prepares your app to handle incoming requests

const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
  context,
  listen: { port: parseInt(process.env.PORT) },
});
```

Comment: are you saying the startStandAloneServer does all 1-3 process in the background?

Comment: Yes. See https://github.com/MichelFloyd/auth-demo/blob/main/server/src/index.ts for the full file - it's part of a GraphQL auth demo built with v4.

Comment: I did get some insights from you auth-demo link however I am using Nestjs and it's not clear how to apply the startStandaloneServer in the main.ts file which is where I want to launch the auth microservice with apollo server ....I have edited my question.